# The notion of smoothness in the local situation

Tags: automorphic-forms, local-fields, smoothness

I am reading Bump's book on Automorphic forms and Representations and I am able to draw a lot of parallels between the theory of $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ which is the infinite place and the theory of $GL(2,F)$ where $F$ is a local field which corresponds to the finite places.

There are notions of smooth functions in both the setups. In the case of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, the smoothness is the usual definition (considering the differential manifold structure on $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$). But in the local case, smoothness is defined to be locally constant.

> **Question.** Is there any differential structure on $GL(2,F)$ which justifies this definition? Or in other words, what is the motivation
> for defining smoothness in this fashion?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you study maps from an $F$-manifold to an $\mathbb{C}$-manifold, and the topologies on those are "incompatible", so there is no choice but to say that a "decent" map should be locally constant. It is instructive to first think what you would like to be smooth functions from $F$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Or, similarly, a test case you can make is that of basic abelian character theory. Are locally constant functions enough to contain Fourier theory, i.e. are continuous homomorphisms from, say, $F^{\times}$ to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ necessarily locally constant? The answer is yes, by a "no small subgroups" argument.

(So, indeed, in a more "advanced", or "recent", theory of representations of $G(F)$ over $F$ (which I don't know), one would indeed have some analytic functions, given by power series, etc.)

Comment: I kind of get that the incompatibility of topologies argument leads to considering locally constant functions. But why the term "smooth"? Can't it be just said that "We need to consider functions which respect the topological group structure on both sides (i.e. the $F$ side and $\mathbb{C}$ sides) and they turn out to be locally constant ones." ?

Comment: I don't have a complete explanation of why "smooth", I guess this is partly historical. For example, why not "analytical" (as K-finite vectors in the real setting are analytical etc.)... Probably not that important in the end, it is just the natural thing to consider for $\mathbb{C}$-reps. of $F$-groups...

Comment: I agree that this is just a matter of terminology, but the motivation behind my question was to understand whether there is some differentiable structure hiding somewhere. From your answer I understand that the condition of local finiteness should be imposed just to get a morphism of topological groups... Lets see if someone else can give the reason to why its called smooth... Thank you for your answer @Sasha

Comment: $G(F)$ has a differentiable structure (an "$F$-analytic manifold") but it is irrelevant for representations over $\mathbb{C}$ (it will only become relevant when you start to think about something like representation over $F$). For representations over $\mathbb{C}$, it is enough to know that it is totally disconnected Hausdorff space. I guess "smooth" is by some analogy with the case of representations of $G(\mathbb{R})$, where you have smooth vectors etc., and not by some intuition like you try someone to give (that those are actually smooth in some formal setting etc.).